# Let's give some examples of Great Questions or Answers!

Tags: discussion, site-improvement

I figured since we're in the private beta stage, that we can use some more 'refining' of what's good and bad for this site. I suggest placing questions and/or answers that are of **high quality** as 'answers' to this question. Users can then up-vote or down-vote as they agree or disagree.

**Note:** Please DO NOT place your own questions or answers in here.  This is not meant to be a promotion of your question, but rather a place to learn from other's success's.  I personally will seriously consider down-voting a self promoted question/answer.

Comment: Can you clarify what would be different or of additional benefit to just ranking questions and answers based on the regular voting system on the main site? Something upvoted is probably good, and it's the same people voting on the same Q&A's here...

Comment: @Greg while the voting system is great, not everyone will see every question.  Also the voting system IMO is faulted by the, what I call, "everyone voted so should I" curse.  Whenever we see a highly up-voted question many times we automatically assume it's good, which in most cases is.  But by bringing those questions into a place where discussion and analysis can be done I believe makes the difference here.

Comment: Also, even poor answers get upvoted, but that doesn't mean we want to see them all over the place @Greg :-)

Comment: This question is still very relevant. I think that the Fitness/Nutrition domain is a particularly tough one to develop good questions for. (It's easy to be too broad, and once you get specific enough, you've usually found your answer.) Therefore examples of great **questions** are doubly important in order for people to emulate them.

Answer (score 4):

[Ivo Flipse's answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/113/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-running-shoe/166#166) to "What should I look for in a running shoe" is a perfect example of well documented answer that is beneficial to the general public:

Here's an excerpt:

> **So how do I know which one I need?**
>
> Well one easy way of determining this is looking back at your history:
>
> 1. You never had anti-pronation shoes and didn't sustain any injuries? --> Get neutral shoes
> 2. Do you run a lot and for long distances? Neutral shoes
> 3. You're not overweight? --> Neutral shoes unless move point 3 applies. If not, more stable shoes
> 4. Did you ever have any injuries that are linked to pronation? Get more stable shoes.
>
> If you're overweight and you have a history of pronation-related injuries then yes, probably you need the heaviest kind of support you can get. In most other cases, the neutral shoe is of such decent quality that you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Ivo Flipse's answer to my question [Home Gym: Is an elliptical trainer alone enough?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/312/home-gym-is-an-elliptical-trainer-alone-enough/360#360)

Only one upvote at the time of writing, but I really do think detailed answers with original content like that one will ultimately be the difference between this being a mediocre site and a serious resource for professionals, enthusiasts and the general public alike.

Answer (score 1):

[Berin Loritsch's](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/879/berin-loritsch) reply to the, [800 Calorie Diet](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/800-calorie-diet)

Excerpt:

> The diet I'm including in my answer is safe, but has a marginally higher daily calorie intake. It originated with a Dr. Tran in France about 30 years ago, made it to Canada, and about two years ago was approved by the FDA for the USA. It's typically administered by doctor's offices or health clinics.
>
> Ideal Protein Diet
>
> It operates on the basic principle that the modern diet typically has far too much sugar and other insulin inducing chemicals. As a result, our pancreas gets overworked and produces too much insulin (trapping the calories as fat and making you hungry again). The diet consists of four phases:
>
> Phase 1: let the pancreas rest and lose weight. (80-90% of weight loss goal)
>
> Phase 2: get the stomach used to digesting more whole proteins (remainder of weight loss goal)
>
> Phase 3: reintroduce carbs safely.
>
> Phase 4: maintenance